# Why does java.util.Optional.ofNullable() expect @NonNullable?

Tags: java, annotations, nullable, eclipse-jdt, type-mismatch

Trying to wrap my head around why a utility class whose sole purpose is to wrap null, expects `@NonNullable` argument. Example below produces unexpected (to me) null type mismatch errors in Eclipse.

> Null type mismatch (type annotations): required '@NonNull IoSession'
> but this expression has type '@Nullable IoSession'

I wouldn't have written the code this way, but I'm stuck between the coding standards of a 3rd party I'm trying to contribute to, and the realities of a 4th party library whose interface I'm trying to implement, so I'm stuck trying to make everyone happy while still making everything work.

Given the specific callback method signature, what is the best way to handle the implementation correctly while producing the least compiler warnings (before applying suppression). Before trying `java.util.Optional`, I was just doing simple null checks, but as you know, the compiler still warns of

> Potential null pointer access: this expression has a '@Nullable' type

in spite of the null check... another 3rd party coding standard is no compiler errors or warnings, while using the least suppression possible, to achieve that.

```
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.mina.core.buffer.IoBuffer;
import org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession;
import org.apache.mina.filter.codec.CumulativeProtocolDecoder;
import org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderOutput;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

@NonNullByDefault // @NonNullByDefault required and enforced by frameworks coding standards (3rd party) 
public class MyClass extends CumulativeProtocolDecoder {
    
    @Override          // implementation of 4th party callback, necessitating @Nullable annotation
    protected boolean doDecode(@Nullable IoSession s, @Nullable IoBuffer i, @Nullable ProtocolDecoderOutput o) {

        Optional<IoSession> session = Optional.ofNullable(s); // Null type mismatch (type annotations): required '@NonNull IoSession' but this expression has type '@Nullable IoSession'
        Optional<IoBuffer> in = Optional.ofNullable(i); // Null type mismatch (type annotations): required '@NonNull IoBuffer' but this expression has type '@Nullable IoBuffer'
        Optional<ProtocolDecoderOutput> out = ofNullable(o); // Null type mismatch (type annotations): required '@NonNull ProtocolDecoderOutput' but this expression has type '@Nullable ProtocolDecoderOutput'

        
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the warnings. There are no annotations in the Java `Optional`

Comment: So then the `@NonNullByDefualt` annotation on the class must cause non-annotated arguments to inherit the `@NonNullable` default. It seems like there are two different null-handling paradigms that don't play perfectly together.

Comment: Yes, I think so. The javadoc states *Applying this annotation to a declaration has the effect that type references, which are contained in the declaration, and for which a null annotation is otherwise lacking, should be considered as @NonNull.*

Comment: I was afraid I might be asking a bit of a political question. I think that in this case I'm going to push back on the 3rd parties coding standards since I'm supplying the concrete implementation for a 4th party interface and it doesn't make sense to allow the 3rd party to dictate the annotations in this context, since the net result ends up being the opposite of the intent. These are OSGI bundles and what I have here smells more like contract issues, where the type mismatches are but a symptom of that smell.